# ARR w/ URL Rewrite on IIS 7 - Browser identifier incorrect

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, arr

I've been able to get IIS 7 with ARR and URL rewrite to work perfectly! Now my problem is, when I go to "http://support.mydomain.com.ph" it goes to my OTRS server perfectly BUT it gives me a browser warning that my browser is too old - when in fact I'm using the latest version of Firefox.

I'm thinking this is because of the URL rewrite or ARR using IIS7's IE classification which in turn gets passed as some sort of header to the OTRS web server.

I don't really know what the problem is but exchange OWA is working properly, main website is working properly, redirect to OTRS is working properly - except the old browser warning.

See screenshot below of latest Firefox and IE6 (running in a VM Win2k3R2). This is all just a learning environment.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of ARR or the URL Rewrite module throwing an old browser warning.  Are you sure this isn't a function of the software itself?  Its possible that the software doesn't know how to read the CUA string for the latest version of FireFox.

Regardless, this doesn't sound like a server issue but instead a software/application issue.

Comment: If I use latest IE or Firefox directly (meaning type in URL: http://172.16.9.xx/otrs/index.pl) it goes in just fine and I can login.

Comment: OK.  You may need to check that ARR is forwarding the request with the user-agent string from the client properly.  Sounds like some of the header information is being stripped.

Comment: I'd try and post a link to a picture but somehow...With all this ARR and URL Rewrite thing, I can't get my public facing IIS server to serve up an image.

Comment: http://support.dcs.com.ph/example.png and curiously, if I use "www.dcs.com.ph/example.png" it doesn't work! hah! but the image is located in the root directory. very very weird!